# Algorithm for Hasse diagram showing subset inclusion

Tags: algorithm, set, subset, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am looking for an algorithm to construct the Hasse diagram representing a collection of integer sets, ordered by subset inclusion. I have found many discussions and publications on Frequent Itemset analysis (Norris, Ganter, Bordat, ..) but they doesn't seem to give pointers to work on the more fundamental task of just building a lattice representing some given itemsets.
I can think of a naive method where one first compares the sets all against all, then uses one of the known algorithms for transitive reduction.
Can one improve on this and avoid explicit comparison between all sets?

Comment: is the collection of integer sets the power-set or are there sets missing?

Comment: The collection would be any subset of the powerset. We could represent the starting data as a collection of sets of integers, or as a colection of bitvectors where bit positions correspond to integers. Would not matter.

Comment: Ok. Might take some time to complete this, but I think I have a solution.

Comment: Well, I've done what I could, but in the end I could only come up with a few optimizations. The rest was still `O(n ^ 2)` considering set-operations including comparison as `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, your effort is much appreciated!